# Angular 7 Property 'share' does not exists in type observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7

I was writing CachcingServiceBase in Angular 7 but the following error seems to be hit "the observable share is not a function"

```
import "rxjs/add/operator/share";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

export abstract class CachcingServiceBase {
  protected cache<T>(getter: () => Observable<T>,
                     setter: (val: Observable<T>) => void,
                     retreive: () => Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
    const cached = getter();
    if (cached !== undefined) {
      return cached;
    } else {
      const val = retreive().share();
      setter(val);
      return val;
    }
  }
}
```

am i importing the share operator wrong? how can i solve this ? . I tried to import in other ways too but could not solve the issue

Comment: What version of rxjs are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the response the bellow answer solved the issue , it rxjs 6.3.3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrong import and wrong usage :

```
import { share } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

export abstract class CachcingServiceBase {
  protected cache<T>(getter: () => Observable<T>,
                     setter: (val: Observable<T>) => void,
                     retreive: () => Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
    const cached = getter();
    if (cached !== undefined) {
      return cached;
    } else {
      const val = retreive().pipe(share());
      setter(val);
      return val;
    }
  }
```

}